# datatables Ajax-Error / http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I use datatable in laravel web application.
When i show 6 column its working fine, but when adding one more column,i get the error http://datatables.net/tn/7

Here the table Header

```
<table class="datatable mdl-data-table dataTable" cellspacing="0"
    width="100%" role="grid" 
    style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here the view

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{{ route('api.GetData') }}',
        columns:[
        {$data:'id', name:'id'},
        {$data:'first_name', name:'first_name'},
        {$data:'last_name', name:'last_name'},
        {$data:'email', name:'email'},
        {$data:'gender', name:'gender'},
        {$data:'country', name:'country'},
        {$data:'salary', name:'salary'}
        ]
    });
});
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: From the error page: `This occurs when jQuery falls into its error callback handler, which will typically occur when the server responds with anything other than a 2xx HTTP status code.` Your AJAX request is failing. You need to diagnose why that is on your server.

Comment: what's the response of your ajax when you add one column ?

Comment: Here pic of ajax response http://imgur.com/Uzw7br7

Comment: i think my code looks fine and I can't find anything wrong.